# Only one of two arguments should be defined

Tags: perl

What is the more elegant way to write the next?

```
sub depend {
    my($x,$y) = @_;
    die "only one allowed" if( defined($x) && defined($y) );
    die "one must be defined" unless ( defined($x) || defined($y) );
    if( defined($x) ) {
         $y = somefunc($x);
    } else {
         $x = somefunc($y);
    }
    return($x,$y);
 }
```

The function should get exactly only one argument. If get defined both = error, if defined none = error. And the undefined arg is calculated based on the defined one.

Comment: So someone might invoke the sub as `depend(undef, "some arg")`?

Comment: @JeffFrench yes, someone cound call it as \@pair = depend($v1,$v2); and the $v1 is undefined and $v2 defined.

Comment: This looks like an overly permissive API. Any reason you can't just require the first argument and have the second be optional?

Comment: @chepner think about x,y as width and height of an image - and you want calculate the proportional resize - if one dimension is defined (doesn't matter what one) the second is calculated. For proportional resize, you can't have defined both, or only the 1st one (width).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `xor`, i.e. the "exclusive or":

```
sub depend {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    die "Exactly one must be defined.\n" unless defined $x xor defined $y;

    if (defined $x) {
         $y = somefunc($x);
    } else {
         $x = somefunc($y);
    }
    return($x, $y);
 }
```

**Update:** You can shorten the rest of the sub, too. Instead of the `if` part, just put

```
return ($x // somefunc($y), $y // somefunc($x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I might define the subroutine to take *two* arguments, but treat them as a key-value pair. To use the width/height example from your comment:

```
sub depend {
    my $key = shift;
    my $value = shift;
    die "One parameter only" if @_;
    return ($value, calc_height($value)) if $key eq "width";
    return (calc_width($value), $value) if $key eq "height";
    die "Must specify either height or width, not $key";
}

my ($w1, $h1) = depend( width => 5 );
my ($w2, $h2) = depend( height => 10 );
my ($w3, $h3) = depend();  # ERROR Must specify either height or width
my ($w4, $h4) = depend( other=>3 );  # ERROR Must specify either height or width, not other
my ($w5, $h5) = depend( foo => bar, 7); # ERROR, One parameter only
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sub f 
{
  my ($x, $y) = @_; 
  die "BOOM" if (defined $x ? 1 : 0) + 
                (defined $y ? 1 : 0) != 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `xor` might not be intuitive, and solution below could easily be extended to more input arguments,

```
 sub depend {
    my($x,$y) = @_;

    die "There should be only one!" if (grep defined, $x,$y) != 1;

    if( defined($x) ) {
         $y = somefunc($x);
    }
    else {
         $x = somefunc($y);
    }
    return($x,$y);
}
```

Comment: In fact, this does not work: `Use of uninitialized value $x in concatenation (.) or string at bad.pl line 25.`

Comment: @mpapec: What about both values undefined?

Comment: @mpapec - Yes, this fails when on `depend(undef, undef);`.

Comment: Updated comparison operator. How does it now look to you?